# Cors configuration in .NET Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, cors, .net-core

Is there any difference between using

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("*"));
```

and

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin());
```

I'm assuming "*" is a wildcard for any origin and that
these should be equivalent. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your methods add `*` as origin, but `builder.AllowAnyOrigin()` also clear all other registered origins inside `builder`, so it is better to use it.

From the [source code](https://github.com/HydAu/AspNetCors/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Cors/CorsPolicyBuilder.cs):

```
public CorsPolicyBuilder WithOrigins(params string[] origins)
{
     foreach (var req in origins)
     {
        _policy.Origins.Add(req);
     }

     return this;
}

public CorsPolicyBuilder AllowAnyOrigin()
{
     _policy.Origins.Clear();
     _policy.Origins.Add(CorsConstants.AnyOrigin);
     // `CorsConstants.AnyOrigin` conts has `*` as value
     return this;
}
```